# Android Google Maps Api Errors

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-manifest, manifest

I have been recently following this tutorial - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html I have come across this error when adding `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` to my android manifest. The error I get is `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`. Could somebody have a look at the tutorial and give me some help. Thanks

Comment: It means that "Google Play Services" are not available on the device. Are you using an Emulator to test the app?

Comment: you are using Google map v1 which is no longer supported. you should be using google maps v2 http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

Comment: @LukasKnuth Yes, I am

Comment: @tyczj Is it possible to edit my code to work?

Comment: @Cj1m I will not edit your code for you, look at the link i provided and start over using that. If you have problem then come back and ask it

Comment: @tyczj I have tried to start over, I can't find any code that works